# Sequence of bounded functions or pointwise bounded

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

We have sequence of function $\{f_n(x)\}$ defined on set $E$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. What does mean *sequence of bounded functions*? Is it *pointwise bounded*?

**Definition:** We say that $\{f_n\}$ is *pointwise bounded* on $E$ if the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is bounded for every $x\in E$, that is, if there exists a finite-valued function $\phi$ defined on $E$ such that $$|f_n(x)|<\phi(x) \quad (x\in E, n\in \mathbb{N}).$$

Can anyone explain to me please?

Comment: just to add.why it is NOT pointwise bounded because once we know that it has uniform convergence it implies  pointwise boundedness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bounded function is a function whose range is contained in a finite interval. A sequence of bounded functions has the property that each of its individual functions $f_n$ has such a limited range (but the overall range of the collection may still be infinitely large).

The sequence is pointwise bounded if *for every $x$ separately* the sequence $f_n(x)$ is contained in a finite interval. That is a different condition.

Comment: So sequence of bounded functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ means that $|f_n(x)|<M_n$ for any $n$. Right?

Comment: Exactly. And pointwise bounded sequence means that $|f_n(x)|<m_x$ for any $x.$